# Why z-index in css can't be accessed through javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I created a button of Id tag.When I clicked it, I want it to display a div with z-index 1.But why z-index can't be accessed through javascript:

```
var tag = document.getElementById('tag');
tag.onclick = function(){

   var tag_div = document.createElement("div");
   tag_div.id = "wow";
    document.body.appendChild(tag_div);
    tag_div.style.border = "1px solid black";
   tag_div.style.position = "absolute";
   tag_div.style.top = "200px";
   tag_div.style.left = "70px";
   tag_div.style.z-index = 1;
      return false;
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but I would advocate the use of jQuery, it will make your life much easier.

Comment: Have you thought about using jQuery .prop? (.attr's replacement)

Comment: `tag_div.style.z` ***minus*** `index` cannot have a value assigned to it.

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: @felix i use firebug and it says invalid assignment left hand side

Comment: Ah well, that is indeed not very intuitive. The error means that you are trying to assign a value to something that it is not a variable or property (another *value* in most cases). The `-` is interpreted as minus operator, hence  `tag_div.style.z - index` *produces* a value and you cannot assign to it. Here is a simpler example: `5 = 'foo';` or `45 - 3 = '42';`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CSS rules in stylesheets use hyphens, CSS *properties* use camel case, so you need `.zIndex`

Comment: sorry for my foolish but is there any reference for me to refer to?

Comment: I can't find one just now, but the obvious point is that a property name (when given as a _token_) cannot contain a hyphen.

Comment: Use the DOM inspector in firebug

Comment: @dramasea: Here is at least a list of properties: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-extended.

Answer (score 4):

As a general rule of thumb, CSS styles that include hyphens (for the purpose of javascript access) are converted to [camelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase). That is to say, `z-index` becomes `zIndex` just like `background-color` becomes `backgroundColor`.

See [JavaScript and CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/JavaScript):

> In JavaScript, `backgroundColor` corresponds to the CSS property `background-color`. JavaScript does not allow hyphens in names, so "camelCase" is used instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
tag_div.style.zIndex = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code:

```
tag_div.style.z-index = 1;
```

This is invalid Javascript code because of the hyphen -- Javascript sees the hyphen as a minus sign, and interprets it as a subtraction, which will fail.

If you need to access an object property whose name contains a hyphen, you must use the following syntax instead:

```
obj['property-name']
```

This is a general rule for all JS properties.

However specifically for CSS properties, they are generally exposed to Javascript using camel-case names rather than hyphenated names (camel-case means no hyphens, but capitalised letters for new words where a hyphen would have been), so the following should work:

```
tag_div.style.zIndex = 1;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It is never legal JS, not even if tag_div.style.z was a var and index was a var - you would get _illegal assignment left of = sign_

Comment: oops, yes - distracted by the phone call I'm on!

Comment: do you have any reference so that i can refer to??

Comment: You don't need a reference, object literal keys cannot contain hyphens.  Just don't do it :)  Just follow Spudley's example for general JavaScript object properties.  For z-index it would be tag_div.style.zIndex.  Get comfortable with your DOM inspector.

Answer (score 1):

All CSS rules that have dashes (background-image, z-index, margin-top) can be accessed through JavaScript using camelCase property values like:

```
div.style.backgroundImage
div.style.zIndex
div.style.marginTop
```

Answer (score 0):

It is:

```
tag_div.style.zIndex = 1;
```